Why wicket autoconfiguration with Spring Boot not working?
I am trying to use this library
https://github.com/MarcGiffing/wicket-spring-boot
I included the maven library. I copied @SpringBootApplication class, HomePage class and HomePage html. As far as I understood after only this it should work. I can start the application but but at localhost:8080 I see
Internal error
Return to home page
What am I missing?
Update stacktrace
org.apache.wicket.markup.MarkupNotFoundException: Can not determine Markup. Component is not yet connected to a parent. [Page class = com.example.demo.HomePage, id = 0, render count = 1]

You are missing to share many details that would help us to help you! Internal error means that there is an exception logged with explanation what is going wrong.

This is what I missed in the pom file
</build>
</project>
....
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
</resources>

